# Only show title of referenced node in a view if the node contains files in another field?

Tags: views

Content-type-A has files attached. Content-type-B has a node reference to multiple Content-type-A's.

I making a view which is attached to Content-type-B. It needs to show each Content-type-A title that is referenced and also the files attached to each Content-type-A.

This is easy to do with relationships however I need the Content-type-A title to not be shown if there are no files attached to it.

So if I have this:

NodeB has a node reference to NodeA, NodeA2 and NodeA3.

NodeA and NodeA2 have a file attached but NodeA3 does not.

Then I need my view to just be this:

```
NodeA
-File from NodeA
NodeA2
-File from NodeA2
```

But its currently this:

```
NodeA
-File from NodeA
NodeA2
-File from NodeA2
NodeA3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view has all the info you want (and then some); simply override the view template or use hook_view_preview() to unset/hide the result you dont want.

There are many examples of this on the web and in documentation.